# Using sed to replace '½' with '.5'

Tags: regex, sed

How can I use sed to replace `½` with `.5`?

Comment: this is answer. sed -i 's/½/\.5/g' input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal needs to support Unicode then this works:

```
x='sed to replace "½"'
echo "$x"| sed 's/½/.5/'
sed to replace ".5"
```

To substitute this in in-line in a file:

```
sed -i.bak 's/½/.5/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

:) you have to use an escape character to be able to parse 1/2 on command-line like this.

echo "anyrandom text 1/2 asdf 1/2" | sed 's/1/2/0.5/g'

/g at the end make it replace all the occurrences of the pattern.

if you want to run it on a file:  sed 's/1\2/0.5/g' filename